# How to Automatically Run a Batch File on a Self-Cleaning Virtual Machine?

Tags: bash, powershell, batch-file, group-policy, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to learn a little bit of test automation. I know some batch files, I am brushing up my "*PowerShell*" skills and - who knows - I might even end up using some `bash`, in the long run.

I have this self-cleaning virtual machine that gets completely wiped-out after an user log-out. Upon the next user log-in, the Registry and the start-up folders get cleared. All I can do is to manually double-click on desktop icons in order to start some static software applications that I am recurrently using.

The batch file part I have managed to do by myself. I am enabling the execution of local "*PowerShell*" scripts and then running a script that is changing some desktop icons. Here is how the `Change_Desktop_Icons.BAT` batch file is looking right now:

[The Batch-File](https://github.com/DOBRESCUMihai19/Shell-Scripting/blob/main/Change_Desktop_Icons.BAT)

The "*PowerShell*" part has nicely been debugged by some great people who are roaming about on this website and for whose help I am thanking them again. Great lessons I am learning here every day.

This is the "*PowerShell*" Script:

[The PowerShell-Script](https://github.com/DOBRESCUMihai19/Shell-Scripting/blob/main/Change_Desktop_Icons.PS1)

The `bash` part has not been written yet.

Now, the problem is that I always have to manually double-click on `The_Start-Me-Up_Cake` desktop icon. After the manual double-click and the execution of the scripts, the desktop icons get nicely changed, as it can be seen in the picture that appears below.

[image: Desktop Icons]

What I am now looking for is to somehow automate even the manual double-click. I am aware that the "*Task Scheduler*" static software application might be used in this respect, but I do not fully know how.

This is the output of the double-click on `The_Start-Me-Up_Cake` Desktop Icon:

[The Output of the Double-Click](https://github.com/DOBRESCUMihai19/Shell-Scripting/blob/main/Change_Desktop_Icons.BAT.OutPut.TXT)

The virtual machine is quite tightly set up. I am not allowed to use certain static software applications such as, for instance, the "*Group Policy*".

At this point, I have posted this question on the "*Stack Overflow*" website. Apparently, due to the fact that it is less related to the Software Development process and more suited for the general Personal Computer usage, the question has been closed.

I am pasting here the two comments that I have received on this question.

- Add a scheduled task to run the PowerShell script on logoff. There's plenty of articles around that demonstrate how to do this – Scepticalist yesterday
- I agree with @Scepticalist. Also, isn't there a public folder on your V.M.? You can also toss it in there and have it run at log-in/start-up – Abraham Zinala yesterday

These are the two comments that I have appended to the question in order to reply to the commenters:

- Unfortunately, it seems that I am not allowed to create a scheduled task on this virtual machine, @Scepticalist. I am checking its user name and it is perfect. I am copy-pasting its password, so I know for sure that it is all right. The only remaining cause for the happening of this weird behavior might be the fact that the system administrative team could have enforced a while ago some kind of group policies that are currently disabling the creation of scheduled tasks by the users of these virtual machines. – Mihai Dobrescu 22 hours ago
- Indeed, @Abraham Zinala, there are a few directories that I am still allowed to use and that are intact after the logoff/logon process couple. The desktop folder is `\\<server>.<domain>.eu\<share>$\<path>\Desktop\` . I am also attempting to maintain the shell-scripts in the `Y:\Digitization\GitHub\Shell-Scripting\`  folder. I do not know how to place a scheduled task in either of these directories, but - first of all - apparently I am not allowed to create any kind of scheduled tasks, at all, on this virtual machine. – Mihai Dobrescu 22 hours ago

After my latest two comments, to my surprise, I have managed to create the scheduled task somehow. I cannot explain why this time it did not ask me for my credentials. It simply created it and saved it.

I have tested it and it was nicely running the `Change_Desktop_Icons.BAT` batch file. The problem is that the same thing did not happen at the user logon, when I want it to be run.

Is there a way to save the scheduled task in the `Y:\Digitization\GitHub\Shell-Scripting\`  folder, for example? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it! To run the scheduled task at logon, select that option from the list of triggers in the "Create basic task" wizard:

[image]

I would recommend running powershell directly from the task scheduler instead of using the batch script. These are the steps to follow in the wizard:

- Action: Start a program
- Program: Browse to Powershell.exe, usually within `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
- Arguments: copy and paste the text below. It has to be all one line:

```
-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -f Y:\Digitization\Powershell\The_My_Computer_Desktop_Icon\Change_Desktop_Icons.PS1
```

Do be aware that some scripting and automation like this can get you in trouble with your IT admins if they're cranky

Comment: This is the problem. After the next logon, everything is somehow wiped out. The Registry is cleared, the Start-Up folder is cleared, and - most unfortunately - all of the Scheduled-Tasks are deleted. So, the question was whether there is a way to save them on one of those above-mentioned locations or if there is another solution to this problem. Remember: it _is_, after all, just a Virtual-Machine.

Comment: The other answer that I was waiting for was the one of the following kind: "_Talk to your System Administrative Team!_". Well - you know - it _is_ a bank. Security is crazy down here. Not only that their regular answer is "No", but they even make you delete some e-mails from the Recoverable Deleted Items folder sometimes.

Comment: @MihaiDobrescu In that case, the easiest thing you can really do yourself is what you already have: a batch script that you can run manually when you log on.

Comment: This depends on the company culture, but it may be worthwhile to make an IT request for a logon script to be created for your user account. If it's an issue like eye strain and/or your manager approves it, all the better. No guarantees though - I've worked in a banking environment and the requirements are... insane.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @user19702, for your answer and for your comments. I guess that this concludes the introspection related to this question. Yes, I am myself sometimes manually double-clicking that `Change_Desktop_Icons` Desktop Icon that I have created for running that Batch-File after my log-on process. It was just a pretext, though, for testing how far one can go with automation under these circumstances. Not very far, apparently. «_Insanity_» is an outdated term for these novel days. I suggest a new, much trendier expression: «_Planetary Schizophrenia_».